# Rendering a 'show' template with an additional parameter is causing a routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a template "groups/show.html.erb" I have link that renders a partial by passing a parameter to the controller.  The controller then uses the parameter to identify which JS call to make.

```
<%= link_to 'Add a Video', group_path(create_video: true), remote: true %>
```

then in the controller

```
elsif params[:create_video]
  @video = Group.find(params[:id]).videos.build
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render action: 'create_video'}
  end
```

This brings up a partial with a form that creates a video using the create method in the videos_controller.  If a validation on the form fails and I try to render "groups/show" I get a routing error:

_create_video.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @video, :url => group_videos_path(@group) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups", :create_video=>true}

To make this work I think you can just explicitly match it in routes.rb but is there a better way to do it?  Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to give which group, you should normally do something like

```
group_path(@group, create_video: true)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Correct thank you.  It's strange that I don't need to specify which group when the page originally loads but I do after the render.  Why is this the case?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I have seen that as well. I think rails, if no parameters are given, will look for the `@group` instance-variable. If you give any parameters, it will use that instead. I always try to be explicit, and specify the object you want to show the path to.

Comment: I don't think that's it because I didn't have @group specified but still had a parameter and it was working fine before the model validation.  I think it has something to do with because I'm rendering "show" from a different controller it gets confused about the URL and so doesn't automatically add the named id.  When I go back to show from the render the URL becomes /groups/:id/videos, not sure why it's doing that.

Comment: @steve: I hope you do not expect me to say something sensible about all that you just said. I need much more info to be able to say something. _It worked before, from a different controller, but now it doesn't, and the url changes._ I need to see code to be able to help you. _When I go back to show from the render_ : what is that? Do you click the back-link from a view, do you click a link in the view? Is the view rendered correctly or not? Does the controller redirect you or is the link wrong?

Comment: Yes sorry, that wasn't the best writeout :) I think I'm going to make a separate question on this.

Comment: here, thx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280070/ajax-rendering-is-messing-up-my-routes