# AJAX rendering is messing up my routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have two controllers magazines and articles, articles is a nested route of magazines.  When I'm in `/magazines/show` there's a basic form to create an article

```
<%= form_for @article, :url => magazine_articles_path(@magazine), remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', target: @article %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When this submits it gets sent to the articles controller.  In the articles controller I render an action that rerenders this form (I'm rerendering the form to get rid of the errors if there are any)

```
$('#id').html('<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'create_article' %>');
```

This however changes the form's action to `/magazines/:id/articles` instead of `/magazines/:id`

Initial Form:

```
<form id="new_article" class="new_article" method="post" data-remote="true" action="/magazines/1/articles" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Form after rerendering:

```
<form id="edit_article_3" class="edit_article" method="post" data-remote="true" action="/magazines/1/articles" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

This messes up my routing and gives me routing errors if I try to submit this form again.  I'm guessing this is occuring because the new `@article` is coming from the articles controller.  A little more detail of how this happens and a clean solution to get around it would be much appreciated.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Is the same form rendered in both cases?

Comment: @nathanvda yes the same code (same partial) is being rendered, but rails is changing the HTML generated, I edited my question to include this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! In the second case your `@article` already exists, and your form should look as follows:

```
<%= form_for @article, :url => magazine_articles_path(@magazine, @article), remote: true do |f| %>
```

So to explain it more: since the `@article` exists, you should make it clear which `@article` is being edited. If the article does not exist yet, it just needs to create the new article.

It is possible that the path-helper can handle new records vs. exisiting records itself, otherwise you will have to do something like

```
<% post_url = @article.new_record? ? magazine_articles_path(@magazine) : magazine_articles_path(@magazine, @article) %>
<%= form_for @article, :url => post_url, remote: true do |f| %>
```

Hope this helps.